# AWS CloudFormation: how can I use parameters to form strings?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

What I want to achieve is this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: deploy a full stack

Parameters:
  # Product Name:
  ProductName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'Docloud'
    Description: This is the string that will appear in the names of most resources. 
  # Environment Name:
  EnvName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'test-2'
    Description: This is the string that will appear in the names of most resources. 

  # EC2 instance: 
  InstanceName: 
    Type: String
    # Default: 'Earth-test-1'
    Default: 'Earth-${!ProductName}-${!EnvName}'

  # load balancing 
  NLBName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'NLB-${!ProductName}-${!EnvName}'
    Description: the name for Network Load Balancer

  TargetGroupName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'TG-${!ProductName}-${!EnvName}'
    Description: the name of the Target Group to which the traffic from the NLB goes
```

I want to define 2 parameters: `ProductName` and `EnvName`, and then these variables will appear throughout the template to automatically form strings such as `'TG-${!ProductName}-${!EnvName}'` or `'NLB-${!ProductName}-${!EnvName}'`, so that when I deploy a new stack one week later, I only need to modify `ProductName` and `EnvName`.

I have tried a couple things, but the above goal cannot be reached.

Is this possible with CloudFormation now?

Comment: "I have tried a couple things" - what exactly have you tried? Sadly its not clear what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible, you have to use a nested stack or Aws CDK to have composed variables.